# How to bind and add data in my datagrid from code behind?

Tags: c#, datagrid, silverlight-5.0

How am I managed to add data to my datagrid with 3 columns: Id, FirstName and lastname from codebehind? I will be thankful for your answer

```
 <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding Id}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FirstName" CanUserReorder="True"
                                            CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"
                                       MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBox_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="TextBox_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="TextBlock_MouseMove"/>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="True" 
                CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" >
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" 
                            MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBox_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
                            MouseLeftButtonUp="TextBox_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SetBinding:

```
  var myDataObject = ... // VM possibly
  var myBinding = new Binding("FirstName");
  myBinding.Source = myDataObject;
  myTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

just adapt it and tailor it to your needs.